# xamarin.forms label databinding visibility to different property in viewmodel

Tags: data-binding, xamarin.forms, visibility

in xamarin.forms, I have a label that the text is populated using databinding to a property in the viewmodel.  How can I set the visibility of this label, using databinding, but to a different variable in the viewmodel... not the one the text is bound to?

the other property is an ID number... and I want to say if ID number = 1 then HIDE label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<Label Text="{Binding MyTextProperty}" IsVisible="{Binding MyBooleanProperty}" />

public bool MyBooleanProperty {
  get {
    if (ID == 1) return false;
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: sorry, I should have been more specific, the property is an id number.  so if ID=1, then hide label